# Restrict the execution of a PHP script to one referer

Tags: php, ajax

I am building an ajax/PHP script and I have come up with something to protect the ajax file from external access, by that I mean to restrict the execution of the script from another server (and domain). I am using JQuery `$ajax` to post to the PHP file.

Here is the PHP file:

```
 <?php
 $config["url"]="mysite.com";
 if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"])) {
     $url = parse_url($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]);

     if ($url["host"] != $config["url"]) {
         echo "You don't have access to this file.";
         exit;
     } else { 
         //Run The script
     }
 }
 ?>
```

Basically what this script does is that it matches the Referer and the domain. The script will exit if it doesn't match and will run if it does. So the script can be executed from only `mysite.com` and not from elsewhere.

I am not PHP / Javascript expert, so can anyone tell me if this is good or not and if it will fail under some conditions?

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What this script is protecting against is a *Cross Site Request Forgery* or *CSRF*. Checking the referer is one of the two primary defenses against this attack. The only problem is if the site has any user generated content, then they can add something such as:

```
<img src="/src/to/your/ajax?params=something_evil" />
```

which will still execute it.
The second most common prevention method is using a CSRF token for ajax.
Here are two resources to read up on to find more about this attack:

Description: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)

Prevention: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

**Edit:**

*A little clarification that may clear confusion on the subject.*

Any user can forge the referer header, but this is irrelevant. The reason it doesn't matter is that if they can forge the referer, they can just as easily make a legitimate request.

The important part here is ensuring that they cannot forge a request from **any other user**. This is the only aspect that matters and the only reason for checking the referer and protecting against CSRF attacks.

Comment: This is clearly wrong. I know very little about CSRF protection, however, even in my limited knowledge, I am going to say that checking the referer is definately not a valid means of protecting. I've never researched how to forge referers, yet I know how to do it without even trying, so I'm assuming that other, more dedicated and determined users will be able to do anything they wish... anyway, long comment cut short, this answer has to be wrong.

Comment: @Layke Your comment verifies that, yes, you know nothing about CSRF protection. In CSRF protection you aren't trying to stop the user from doing what they can already do, that would be useless. The point is keeping an attacker from generating requests on behalf of another legitimate user. Please don't make comments on topics you don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

AJAX already has browser-based protection through the *Same Origin Policy*. You do not need referer checks at all.

Comment: If someone copy my Jquery ajax script and then use it from another site, the php script wouldn't execute?

Comment: @Thief is right, but I don't see any harm in being thorough. Security is about redundancy. +1 May I suggest you change your title to something like "AJAX security across domains" or something to that effect? I think it would be more descriptive to someone who needs help with a similar problem. Just a suggestion. :)

Comment: @ThiefMaster that's assuming its requested via AJAX. But you could still make a server-side request to the end point

Comment: The problem isn't with AJAX, it has to do with CSRF attacks.

Comment: @ThiefMaster Correct, but its not the same origin policy that's protecting him.

Answer (score 0):

You can also block access from any external host using .htaccess file.

```
<Files ~ "^\yourajaxfilename.extension">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>
```

For more details http://www.htpasswdgenerator.com/apache/htaccess.html

Comment: This checks the user's ip, not the referer. So unless you have a very limited userbase with static ips it's not really usable.

Comment: basically deny all will block access to all external sources and its what required.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that people could load a page in their browser and then use the Javascript console built into most browsers to load your ajax page, providing whatever get/post data they want. There are other ways of faking the referrer too.

Basically, your method will work against non-technical users, but you will still need to validate all incoming data to make sure it's not going to cause your script to do something you don't want it to do.