# How to know, from what site server is getting request?

Tags: php, dns, xss

How i can avoid cross-site-scripting, by knowing, from what site user is requesting data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']
```

should contain the URL from which the request originates from.

EDIT: If you are actually trying to prevent XSS then it's mostly down to having to make sure you use htmlentities() everywhere you print unfiltered user data, and should really be using it on pretty much all data you print that isn't meant to be viewed as raw HTML.

Although there are bunch of considerations when writing PHP code as well, but they are far too many to discuss here without any pointers.

Comment: It should also be noted that is is absolutely unreliable. Firewalls, proxies may remove it, and as it's a simple http header it is very easy to forge.

Comment: @Maerlyn of course, but we can assume that clients are not the issue... any computer can execute whatever request they like. The issue is most often to prevent sites from doing requests on behalf of clients (which this does prevent in most cases). Although I'm unsure whether he actually wants to prevent some kind of hotlinking or XSS.

Comment: @arnaud576875 definately, I figured that he misused "cross site scripting", but I might be wrong and that it is indeed what he is trying to avoid. And in that case, yes, my answer is not applicable. It would then be time to whip out the rarely seen htmlentities() ;)

Answer (score 7):

> How i can avoid cross-site-scripting

You can't avoid cross-site-scripting by knowing from what site a user is requesting data.

You can avoid cross-site-scripting by properly escaping.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure whether knowing the referrer URL will work for you but

> And most of the time, XSS attacks came from an input or data that are
>   not well filtered or cleaned before showing it to a browser, like
>   cookies/sessions.

Please read the article below which teaches a library to prevent XSS attacks.

Link: http://oozman.com/php-tutorials/avoid-cross-site-scripting-attacks-in-php/

Answer (score 1):

Use `$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]`, but see the responses to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7290182/902654) question.

Answer (score 1):

in $_SERVER array in base case this is  $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] - but if user go to your site from js method like document.location.href = 'yoursite.com'. IE (test on IE7) does not sent to you information about referer through security reason.